# Internet Connection Sharing with ChromeOS

Tags: internet-connection, google-chrome-os, connection-sharing

Is it possible to share my Chromebook's Internet connection with other **devices**?

I have looked around my settings at `chrome://settings`, but I can only find an option to share a wireless network connection with other **local** users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

When I saw that options I got rather excited myself. Unfortunately, it just means: share a password-enabled network with other users. The Chromebook doesn't have the multiple chips to allow what we're looking for.

Originally I thought it was to help us get our Chromecasts on hotel networks, but... no.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a shame - it would have been really handy to be able to share my connection with other devices.

Comment: I've heard the same complaint on multiple channels(chromecast). I just purchased (http://amzn.to/1JhOWIc) and (http://amzn.to/1mTxnUX) they both have interesting potential. I've also heard of raspberrypi+tor for hotel usage.